# how to convert text file to json format in javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a text file like the one below

> ```
> {"id":819827,"nm":"Razvilka","lat":55.591667,"lon":37.740833,"countryCode":"RU"}
> {"id":524901,"nm":"Moscow","lat":55.752220,"lon":37.615555,"countryCode":"RU"}
> {"id":1271881,"nm":"Firozpur","lat":27.799999,"lon":76.949997,"countryCode":"IN"}
> ```

i want this data into correct json format how should i do it
csv format

i am starting like this

```
var cells = str.split('\n').map(function (el) { return el.split(/\s+/); });
```

how should i move further please help

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `JSON.parse`, which can convert JSON strings into JS Objects;

```js
const string = `{"id":819827,"nm":"Razvilka","lat":55.591667,"lon":37.740833,"countryCode":"RU"}\n {"id":524901,"nm":"Moscow","lat":55.752220,"lon":37.615555,"countryCode":"RU"}\n {"id":1271881,"nm":"Firozpur","lat":27.799999,"lon":76.949997,"countryCode":"IN"}`;

var cells = string.split('\n').map(JSON.parse);

// console.log(cells);

// Convert it back into JSON string using `JSON.stringify`
cells = JSON.stringify(cells);

console.log(cells);
```

Comment: Add `JSON.stringify` to your log of `cells` and you'll have answered the OP's question.

Comment: Ahh, good catch. I thought OP just wanted an JS object. Have edited it. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for answering the above json data i am using to plot a graph in js but its not working 

Comment: @minu you could add a new question if is related to graphs. Is there any change you want in my current answer ?